# website loads from the bottom of the page, possibly due to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this website: [here](http://riyoken.com/illogic) : always loads from the bottom of the page. i was thinking that this was just a thing solely on my part. however i recently switched computers and i noticed that the problem was still there. it is possible that i have some script that is causing the page to load from the bottom. as of right now it does that in chrome, and i am pretty sure it does it in firefox as well. if you could please see if there is any scripts that are causing it to load from the bottom of the page it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it because of the embedded music object at the bottom of the page? Seems like it is attempting to focus on that in Chrome.

Comment: For starters the HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the embedded music object at the bottom of the page. It is attempting to focus on that in Chrome.

I created a local copy of your page and removed the object which stopped the issue.

Move the music object to the top of the page and it will stop doing that.

Here is the offending markup:

```
<object height="1" width="1">
    <param name="src" value="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106830429/Zetsuen%20No%20Tempest-%20The%20Civilisation%20Blaster%20Trailer%20Music.mp3">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <embed src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106830429/Zetsuen%20No%20Tempest-%20The%20Civilisation%20Blaster%20Trailer%20Music.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" controller="true" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="1" width="1">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to embed audio files.

Please use the `<audio>` tag. [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)